# Is there a way to get rid of unnecessesary blank space from a section in Crystal reports?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have this section here with only Item yet it prints the whole length..

it does not adjust to the items currently existing on the section. May I ask how do I get rid of this issue?

[large section Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDPd3.png)

[This is the current design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH6Z8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Drag the bottom border of the section up to reduce its height.
Crystal doesn't auto-shrink section height to fit.

Comment: Sir I have added the design its just that the length is fixed I do not know how to make it base its length on the DETAIL section.

Comment: @Hellscythen24 If you open Section Expert and look at your Page Footer section, is the checkbox for "Print at bottom of page" checked?  If it is checked, the report will create white space above the Page Footer section to ensure its content is at the bottom of the page.  Also, if unchecking this causes white space after the page footer section, then you may need to adjust the vertical size property in Page Setup.

Comment: @R.McMillan sir this appears to be in the details section of the report designer.. My problem still persist after that.. my problem is that the length doesn't adjust to the items inside the details section. It is like fixed.. if i print more than it can handle it will print a new reciept with the remaining items so to speak